# What's the powershell syntax for multiple values in a switch statement and set result to variable?

Tags: powershell

i have a requirement in powershell if filename contains abc then set $tablename to abc_stg if filename contains pqr set $tablename to pqr_stg. Can anyone help.

```
switch ($file_name) {
    abc {"dbo.abc_stg"}
    pqr {"dbo.pqr_stg"}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this page: [Using Wildcards with the Switch Statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx#EGC)

In your case:

```
$tablename = switch -wildcard ($file_name)
    {
        "*abc*" { "dbo.abc_stg" }
        "*pqr*" { "dbo.pqr_stg" }
        default { "No match" }
    }
```